# Git package breaks bash-completion?

Tags: bash, git, synaptic

I am about to try and install the git package.
In Synaptic, in the dependencies tab, it writes:

- **Breaks**: bash-completion (<1:1.9-1)
- **Breaks**: *bash-completion* [italicized]

I have the latest version of bash-completion offered by the repository installed (version 1:2.8-1ubuntu1).

I have read that git comes with [some adapted auto-completion features](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks), and I guess that this feature won't actually prevent completion to work in bash, right?

Also, the `apt-get -s install git` command doesn't output anything regarding the bash-completion package.

So my questions are:

- Since I already have the latest version of the bash-completion package installed, what will happen to it upon the particular case of installing git?
- What does the second line in italic mean in this particular context? How are the two lines different and not merged in a single '**Breaks**: bash-completion' line?

**Edit (additional information)**

- I have Linux Mint 19.1 (Ubuntu 18.04 base)
- The repository offers git 1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.4

Comment: What version of Ubuntu or derivative do you have? What exact version of git are you about to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing [this Synaptic bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=742445), which causes it to misparse “Breaks” dependencies. The two packages aren't actually incompatible.

You should be able to install git with some other tool, for example `sudo apt-get install git` in a terminal. It won't have any impact on the `bash-completion` package. I can confirm that there's no problem installing the `git` and `bash-completion` packages together at least on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, and that does allow bash to complete git commands intelligently.

---

The `git` package is incompatible with an old version of the `bash-completion` package, so it declares a dependency `Breaks: bash-completion (<< 1:1.90-1)`, meaning that this git package is incompatible with any version of `bash-completion` that's older than `1:1.90-1`. This is an ancient version that is not present in any currently-supported version of Ubuntu: the oldest supported version (xenial) has `1:2.1-4.2ubuntu1`. The reason for the incompatibility is that the `git` package provides its own script file for bash completion and the structure of bash completion scripts was different in older versions of `bash-completion`.